# Getting map from a JSON object with an array using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to de-serialize a JSON String that contains an array and multiple levels down. I just want the map of the "attributes" property and the "id". Here is an example:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "3252",
            "type": "job_seekers",
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": "nathan",
                "last_name": "taylor",
                "full_name": "nathan taylor",
                "email": "",
                "phone": "",
                "phone_iso2": "CA",
                "date_of_birth": null,
                "summary": "",
                "created_at": "2023-01-03T17:34:57+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2023-04-21T19:16:05+00:00",
                "locale": "en",
                "channel": "web_traffic_referral",
                "channel_source": "",
                "pipeline_source": "self_registered",
                "address1": null,
                "address2": null,
                "town": null,
                "country": null,
                "postcode": null
            },
            "relationships": {
                "answers": {
                    "meta": {
                        "included": false
                    }
                },
                "custom_attributes": {
                    "meta": {
                        "included": false
                    }
                },
                "comments": {
                    "meta": {
                        "included": false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "26346",
            "type": "job_seekers",
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": "spencer",
                "last_name": "gordon",
                "full_name": "spencer gordon",
                "email": "",
                "phone": "",
                "phone_iso2": "US",
                "date_of_birth": null,
                "summary": "",
                "created_at": "2023-01-06T21:52:40+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2023-04-21T19:16:43+00:00",
                "locale": "en",
                "channel": "direct",
                "channel_source": null,
                "pipeline_source": "self_registered",
                "address1": null,
                "address2": null,
                "town": null,
                "country": null,
                "postcode": null
            },
            "relationships": {
                "answers": {
                    "meta": {
                        "included": false
                    }
                },
                "custom_attributes": {
                    "meta": {
                        "included": false
                    }
                },
                "comments": {
                    "meta": {
                        "included": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {}
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();


                List<JobSeeker> myObjects = objectMapper.readValue(EntityUtils.toString(entity), new TypeReference<List<JobSeeker>>(){});

                for (JobSeeker itr : myObjects)
                {
                    System.out.println(itr);
                }
```

Error:

```
SEVERE: null
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<app.JobSeeker>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1752)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1473)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:396)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:252)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3755)
    at app.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Show us the relevant code and any error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse a `List<JobSeeker>`, while your JSON is an *object* with a `data` field that *contains* (what I think is) a `List<JobSeeker>`. So make another wrapper object and parse that instead:

```
class Data {
  // constructor, getter/setter and Jackson annotations omitted
  List<JobSeeker> data;
}
```

then change the parsing: `objectMapper.readValue(EntityUtils.toString(entity), new TypeReference<Data>(){});`

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "data" (class app.Data), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: app.Data["data"])

Comment: @trilogy Add the relevant Jackson wiring: constructor, getter/setter, etc. This code is just an example.